# Variable size input for LSTM in Pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, pytorch

I am using features of variable length videos to train one layer LSTM. Video sizes are changing from 10 to 35 frames. I am using batch size of 1.
I have the following code:

```
lstm_model = LSTMModel(4096, 4096, 1, 64)
for step, (video_features, label) in enumerate(data_loader):
    bx = Variable(score.view(-1, len(video_features), len(video_features[0]))) #examples = 1x12x4096, 1x5x4096
    output = lstm_model(bx)
```

Lstm model is;

```
class LSTMModel(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, num_classes):
    super(LSTMModel, self).__init__()
    self.l1 = nn.LSTM(input_size=input_size, hidden_size=hidden_size, num_layers=num_layers, batch_first=True)
    self.out = nn.Linear(hidden_size, num_classes)
def forward(self, x):
    r_out, (h_n, h_c) = self.l1(x, None) #None represents zero initial hidden state
    out = self.out(r_out[:, -1, :])
    return out
```

I just want to ask; am I doing the right for training LSTM with variable size input. The code works okay and loss decreases but I am not sure if I am doing the right thing. Because I haven't used LSTMs in Pytorch before.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you code is correct and will work always for a batch size of 1. But, if you want to use a batch size other than 1, you’ll need to pack your variable size input into a sequence, and then unpack after LSTM. You can find more details in [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49473068/7102925).

P.S. - You should post such questions to codereview